# Can I shrink gedit's side panel?

Tags: gedit

My laptop screen is fairly small and gedit's side panel won't go smaller than about 400 px. It is a little exasperating because I can't have any other windows visible if I want to use anything in the sidebar, because it crowds out my document.

Is there a setting someplace that I can fiddle to make it smaller?  I've looked everywhere I can think of for it!

[image: Won't go any smaller]

I can drag it down to the width you see below, but I can't drag it any farther than that.

Comment: Sorry, is what you mean side panel? If it is so, ıt can be smaller than 400px. Could you share a screenshot? So we can easily understand the issue.

Comment: Side panel, yes. Photo added.

Comment: What version is this? I didn't change any setting but I can.

Comment: On my laptop, with knowingly doing anything, I get a minimum width of ~150 px for the side panel (gedit 3.6 on Lubuntu 13.04; Dell Inspiron 1545).

Comment: Gedit 3.4.1 ... on closer inspection, turning off GDP Find seems to resolve the issue. So the plugin is forcing the sidebar out

Comment: File a bug . In the mean time, consider that you don't really need the panel while editing.

Comment: Did that. But I have a plugin (which I like) which checks the syntax on save. So the sidebar is always popping back open. So the solution is indeed to file a bug and get it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out it was a plugin. (GDP Find)

Figured that out by turning off my plugins one by one.