# Resize file browser bar in gedit

Tags: gedit

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I use File Browser Panel plugin in GEdit. I can increase the size of file browser bar. But the minimum width of file browser bar is about 30% of screen width. How to decrease minimum width of the File Browser bar in GEdit?

When I open gedit using terminal then I can decrease the size of the file browser bar. But when I open gedit without using terminal I can't be decrease the size of the file browser bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed GDP plugin from my gedit as mentioned here

[Can I shrink gedit's side panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326731/can-i-shrink-gedits-side-panel)